# Menu button com evento "toggle"

Tags: javascript, menu, javascript-eventos, icons, toggle

Eu estava tentando criar um menu simples, mas descobri que a função toggle está obsoleta.

Qual seria a alternativa atual para criar um evento toggle, já que eu só encontrei respostas antigas?

Quando clicar em `a.menuicon`, o `#menu ul.navigation` desce e se torna visível. Quando clicar novamente, o menu sobe e desaparece. Basicamente, um menu responsivo.

```css
a.menubar { display: none; }
    
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
a.menubar { display: block; }
#menu ul.navigation { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <a class="menuicon" href='#'>Menu</a>

<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Link 1</a>
  <li><a href='#'>Link 2</a>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Quanto ao [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) obsoleto, use [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) no lugar de `toggle()`.

Comment: Olá, Augusto, consegui usando o toggleClass mesmo, deu certo. Andei pesquisando aqui e aparentemente essa é a solução mais usada mesmo. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Exite uma forma, **mas não é indicado pq não é semântico para se fazer um menu**... mas vc pode usar a tag `<details>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lei mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Veja o exemplo

```css
a {display:block}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>MENU</summary>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://facebook.com">FaceBook</a>
</details>
```

Comment: Obrigada, mas de fato não seria semântico. Mas ainda assim, é uma opção.

Answer (score 2):

Pode implementar as transições no elemento usando `:active` para detectar o click.

Segue um norte.

```
#menu:active {
  transition-property: property;
  transition-duration: duration;
  transition-timing-function: timing-function;
  transition-delay: delay

  /* ou pode por tudo em uma linha */
  transition: property duration timing-function delay;
}
```

Comment: Tentei encontrar tutoriais com active, mas eu ainda gostaria de resolver o mistério via Javascript rsrs. Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue sem usar toggle, classList ou className. Basta criar duas regas no CSS usando um atributo `data-ativo`, uma com `display: none` para que o menu já carregue escondido quando for igual a `false`:

```
ul.navigation[data-ativo='false']{
   display: none;
}
```

E outra para mostrar o menu quando o `data-ativo` for `true`:

```
ul.navigation[data-ativo='true']{
   display: block;
}
```

Quando você clicar no link "Menu" e o menu estiver fechado, irá alterar o atributo `data-ativo` para `true`, e se estiver aberto, irá alterar para `false`, e as regras do CSS irão exibir ou mostrar o menu:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   document.querySelector(".menuicon").addEventListener("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var navi = document.querySelector(".navigation");
      var navi_ativo = navi.dataset.ativo;
      navi.setAttribute("data-ativo", navi_ativo == "true" ? "false" : "true");
   });
});
```

```css
ul.navigation[data-ativo='false']{
   display: none;
}

ul.navigation[data-ativo='true']{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
   <a class="menuicon" href='#'>Menu</a>

   <ul class="navigation" data-ativo="false">
     <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Link 1</a>
     <li><a href='#'>Link 2</a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

---

Tem ainda uma outra abordagem mais simples. Quando o elemento está oculto com `display: none`, a sua altura é igual a `0`, com isso você pode alternar entre `display: none` e `display: block` verificando se a altura é igual a `0`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   document.querySelector(".menuicon").addEventListener("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var navi = document.querySelector(".navigation");
      var navi_height = navi.clientHeight || navi.offsetHeight;
      navi.style.display = navi_height ? "none" : "block";
   });
});
```

```css
.navigation{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
   <a class="menuicon" href='#'>Menu</a>

   <ul class="navigation">
     <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Link 1</a>
     <li><a href='#'>Link 2</a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Sam! Funciona perfeitamente também, obrigada! Mas uma dúvida de leigo: esse é um código javascript?

Comment: Sim, é JavaScript. Só o `.navigation{
   display: none;
}` que é CSS.